# wifiManager.AddNetwork return -1 in android 10

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

when we select target sdk to android 9 means pi then all works fine but when we select the target sdk to 10 then wifiManager.AddNetwork(config) return -1 .

Comment: If you want to connect to WiFi in Android 10, you could refer to the example in the link below. https://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2019/11/android-10-wifi.html

Comment: How to enable wifi because setWifiEnabled () deprecated in API level 29?

Comment: For now, you could use `Settings Panels`, which shows a slice of the Android Settings within your App. Please check the link. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/features#settings-panels

Comment: how to open it in xamarin?

Answer (score 2):

> sdk to 10 then wifiManager.AddNetwork(config) return -1 .

**For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always return -1.**

> This method was deprecated in API level 29.
>   a) See WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder#build() for new mechanism to trigger connection to a Wi-Fi network. b) See addNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List), removeNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List) for new API to add Wi-Fi networks for consideration when auto-connecting to wifi.

re: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#addNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that. This response saved me a lot of time, it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: if I set targetSdk to < 29, would it still work on Android 11 devices?